# How to intent from a Fragment Class to an Actiivity class and from an Activity class to a Fragment class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

    if(result.contains("login success")){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Viewlpost.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);         
    }
}
```

> This is my code, to redirect the user from loginactiivty to a fragment activity
>
> This syntax won't work because the application crashes after doing the intent.
>
> I also need a button inside a fragment that needs to redirect to another fragment when clicked. Account to edit account.
>   This is the code

```
changepword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),EditAccount.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to send data from activity to fragment?  You will have to use data in bundle in thay case. Intent is only used to send data between two activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  a fragment to an activity

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ViewLPost.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

From an activity to a fragment it's supposed you want to go back , so finish(); is sufficient to do the task

Comment: what about from a fragment to a fragment?

Comment: @wannabes Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700951/6610790

Answer (score 2):

To pass data from one activity to another activity you must use following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key",data);
startActivity(intent);
```

To pass to a fragment use following lines of code :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("key",data); 

 FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction(); 
 YourFragment fragment = new YoutFragment();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 fragTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, fragment);
 fragTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragments aren't invoked like Activities through an Intent. They can only exist as part off an Activity, that is what they are designed for

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(YourFragment.newInstance(), null);
ft.commit();
```