# How to call a fragment from a OnClick function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to go from fragment_profile to fragment_details while clicking the details button that is found in the fragment_profile. Here is the xml of the button

```
    android:id="@+id/btn_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="onClickDetail"
    app:prof_icon="@string/fa_user"
    app:prof_title="Personal Info" />
```

Now I'm having some difficulties with the onClickDetail function because I don't know how to make the passage from fragment_profile to fragment_detail.

Here is what I've tried so far

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    btn_details.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
        fun onClickDetail(view: View?) {
            val myIntent = Intent(activity, DetailFragment::class.java)
            activity?.finish()
            activity?.startActivity(myIntent)
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32700818/7746134

Comment: That's in java. Im working with Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

You should open fragment via fragment manager like that:

```
activity!!
    .supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, DetailFragment())
    .commitNow()
```

Comment: Hi. Im sorry but I'm pretty new with this things, How do I use this?

Comment: override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) btn_details.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() { fun onClickDetail(view: View?) { activity!! .supportFragmentManager .beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.container, DetailFragment()) .commitNow() } } ) } @MKK